# Projecting list of objects into another type by JsonProperty attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-serialization

I have the following models:

```
class CheckResponse
{
    public ICollection<CheckModel> Checks { get; set; }
}

public class CheckModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public CheckCodes CheckCode { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ResultCode ResultCode { get; set; }
}

public enum CheckCodes
{
    FirstCheck,
    SecondCheck,
    ThirdCheck,
}

public enum ResultCode
{
    Failure,
    Success,
    Warning
}
```

I need to convert `Checks` into `CheckList`:

```
class CheckList
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(CheckCodes.FirstCheck))]
    public bool FirstCheckPassed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(nameof(CheckCodes.SecondCheck))]
    public bool SecondCheckPassed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(nameof(CheckCodes.ThirdCheck))]
    public bool ThirdCheckPassed { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var response = GetResponse();

        var checkResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckResponse>(response);

        // var checkList = ?
    }

    static string GetResponse() => @"{
'checks': [
    {
        'checkCode': 0,
        'resultCode': 1
    },
    {
        'checkCode': 1,
        'resultCode': 2
    },
    {
        'checkCode': 2,
        'resultCode': 0
    }
]}";
}
```

If `resultCode` equals 2 (`ResultCode.Warning`) then check should be passed.

So, the `checkList` should have following properties values:

> FirstCheckPassed = true
>
> SecondCheckPassed = true
>
> ThirdCheckPassed = false

**UPDATED:**

My solution as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
}

static IEnumerable<string> Yield(ICollection<CheckModel> checks)
{
    foreach (var check in checks)
    {
        var success = check.ResultCode == ResultCode.Success || check.ResultCode == ResultCode.Warning;
        yield return "'" + check.CheckCode.ToString() + "': '" + success.ToString() + "'";
    }
}

static void Test()
{
    var response = GetResponse();

    var checkResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckResponse>(response);

    var o = "{" + string.Join(",", Yield(checkResponse.Checks)) + "}";
    var checkList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckList>(o);
}
```

But I'm not sure that this is the best one (Actually, I consider it a little bit ugly). Are there any better approaches?

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft or the new built in Json library?

Comment: I use `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: I would look into making a custom JsonConverter. Are you able to change the format of your json at all?

Comment: No, I get `response` from a web api service, then I need to transform the data exactly the format that I indicated in my question to pass them in another service.

Comment: Rereading the question I think I misunderstood your goal. It sounds like you are able to correctly parse the json response into a `CheckResponse`, and you need help taking that and turning it into an instance of `CheckList`? What should happen if one of the checks doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), with additional change to the POCO you can Deserialize to the exact object you want.

Little change into `CheckResponse`

```
class CheckResponse
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CheckModelConverter))]
    public CheckList Checks { get; set; }
}
```

Adding custom converter

```
public class CheckModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = serializer.Deserialize<CheckModel[]>(reader);
        var result = new CheckList();
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            bool resultValue = item.ResultCode != ResultCode.Failure;
            switch (item.CheckCode)
            {
                case CheckCodes.FirstCheck:
                    result.FirstCheckPassed = resultValue;
                    break;
                case CheckCodes.SecondCheck:
                    result.SecondCheckPassed = resultValue;
                    break;
                case CheckCodes.ThirdCheck:
                    result.ThirdCheckPassed = resultValue;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("No checkcode of " + item.CheckCode);
            }
        }
        return result;  
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Disclosure: I will love more to actually deserialize it to the exact model, and only then Map it (or part of it) into the type i want, this give me more future flexibility and preserve the actual model structure.

**Edit:** Fixed spelling in Disclosure.

Comment: I generally agree that deserializing into a matching model and then mapping is almost always the way to go. I did something like this in my answer, but would also be pretty trivial to set up using something like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

Comment: My thoughts exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method to your `CheckResponse` class like this (note that this could also be an extension method or generally moved elsewhere to keep the code out of your model)

```
public bool CheckPassed(CheckCodes check)
{
  //default to failure if there isn't a matching check
  var result = Checks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CheckCode == check)?.ResultCode ?? ResultCode.Failure;
  return result != ResultCode.Failure;
}
```

and then you could use that method when creating your `CheckList`

```
static void Main()
{
  var response = GetResponse();
  var checkResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckResponse>(response);

  var checkList = new CheckList
  {
    FirstCheckPassed = checkResponse.CheckPassed(CheckCodes.FirstCheck),
    SecondCheckPassed = checkResponse.CheckPassed(CheckCodes.SecondCheck),
    ThirdCheckPassed = checkResponse.CheckPassed(CheckCodes.ThirdCheck)
  };
}
```